# .rb file reads one file but not the other - but they are right next to each other in the file structure...? (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby, erb

I am doing the EventManager tutorial from Jumpstart. My problem is that it is not reading the 'form_letter.erb' file.

My file structure is as follows:

```
~
    event_manager                 (folder/located in root directory)
          lib                     (subfolder of event-manager)
             event_manager.rb     (located in lib)
    event_attendees.cvs           (located in event_manager)
    form_letter.erb               (located in event_manager)
    form_letter.html              (located in event_manager)
    full_event_attendees.cvs      (located in event_manager)
```

I have tried some of the ways I saw in other threads to see where the file is running from , one returned: `home/action` . I tried adding that path to the .erb path, but it didn't work. Interestingly the .rb file is reading the `"event_attendees.csv"` file that is sitting right next to the one it won't read in the file structure. What's going on here? I structured the files and wrote the path exactly as the tutorial showed. I will provide the .rb code for reference:

```
require "csv"
require "sunlight/congress"
require "erb"

Sunlight::Congress.api_key = "e179a6973728c4dd3fb1204283aaccb5"

def save_thank_you_letters(id, form_letter)
  Dir.mkdir("output") unless Dir.exists? ("output")
    filename = "output/thanks_#{id}.html"  
  File.open(filename, 'w') do |file|
    file.puts form_letter 
  end
end

def legislators_by_zipcode(zipcode)
  legislators = Sunlight::Congress::Legislator.by_zipcode(zipcode)
end

def clean_zipcode(zipcode)  
  zipcode.to_s.rjust(5,"0")[0..4]
end


puts "EventManager initialized."


contents = CSV.open "event_attendees.csv", headers: true, header_converters: :symbol  
template_letter = File.read "form_letter.erb"  #<--not being read
erb_template = ERB.new template_letter 

  contents.each do |row|
    id = row[0]
    name = row[:first_name]
    zipcode = clean_zipcode(row[:zipcode])
    legislators = legislators_by_zipcode(zipcode)
    form_letter = erb_template.result(binding)
    save_thank_you_letters(id, form_letter)
    end
```

UPDATE:

I have tried changing the path to:

```
   Filer.read "event_manager/form_letter.erb"
```

And I do not get the error anymore, but I also don't get any indication that anything has happened...I can tell it is running the .rb file because I get the `=> EventManager initialized` as output from terminal with no errors..but the lesson says that at this point if all is going correctly, this code should be creating a directory to store each individual 'thank you' letter in and I am getting no indication that has happened nor do I see any new directories in my file structure. This is my first time doing something like this so I really don't know what I SHOULD be seeing...

Answer (score 0):

Try this `File.read('../form_letter.erb')`

Comment: Thank for your response @jon snow...I ran that within my .rb file and got the same error:  `event_manager/lib/event_manager.rb:28:in read: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ../form_letter.erb (Errno::ENOENT)      ` any other suggestions?

Comment: I am in `event_manager` dir and executed `ruby lib/event_manager.rb` and your ` following line `File.read "form_letter.erb"`` using `ruby 1.9.2p330`. Oh Fk , I have tried same scenario, its working fine for me. Hope i did same thing as you did, but not able to reproduce it. Your more input may help.

Comment: hey jon thanks for checking back! I actually finally figured out that for some reason I had to use  `Filer.read "event_manager/form_letter.erb"` instead. Weird because it read a file right next to it without having to use an exact path. Anyways I got it all worked out now, thanks again:)