# What SHOULD I be seeing to know this code has done what it was supposed to?

Tags: ruby

I am doing the EventManager tutorial from Jumpstart Labs. Originally I could not get it my .rb file to read a .erb file, and I think I may have solved that, but I am not sure as I do not know what I SHOULD be seeing if all is running correctly and unfortunately the tutorial doesn't tell you. Here is my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29622122/rb-file-reads-one-file-but-not-the-other-but-they-are-right-next-to-each-othe)

Now after a simple change, I am no longer getting the error - but I am also not getting any indication that the code is working as expected. The tutorial says that this code should be creating a new directory and storing a copy of each 'thank you' letter into a file called 'output'  in that new directory. But when I run it all I see is the `=> EventManager initialized` from the terminal, which tells me that my .rb is being read and (I think) that the .erb is finally being read...but I do not see any new directories/files in the file structure, nor any indication that anything was created - so I can't tell if it is actually *doing* anything.

I am kind of expecting to see some kind of message telling me the directory has been created, perhaps with a file path or something.

I have never done anything like this and I'm not sure what I *should* be seeing...can anyone tell me how I would know that this code is preforming as expected? And if it is not, why?

```
require "csv"
require "sunlight/congress"
require "erb"

Sunlight::Congress.api_key = "e179a6973728c4dd3fb1204283aaccb5"

def save_thank_you_letters(id, form_letter)
  Dir.mkdir("output") unless Dir.exists? ("output")
    filename = "output/thanks_#{id}.html"  
  File.open(filename, 'w') do |file|
    file.puts form_letter 
  end
end

def legislators_by_zipcode(zipcode)
  legislators = Sunlight::Congress::Legislator.by_zipcode(zipcode)
end

def clean_zipcode(zipcode)  
  zipcode.to_s.rjust(5,"0")[0..4]
end


puts "EventManager initialized."


contents = CSV.open "event_attendees.csv", headers: true, header_converters: :symbol
template_letter = File.read( "event_manager/form_letter.erb")
erb_template = ERB.new template_letter

  contents.each do |row|
    id = row[0]
    name = row[:first_name]
    zipcode = clean_zipcode(row[:zipcode])
    legislators = legislators_by_zipcode(zipcode)
    form_letter = erb_template.result(binding)
    save_thank_you_letters(id, form_letter)
    end
```

Comment: Why not just add some simple output statements in various places? What you "should" be seeing is what it's supposed to be doing, e.g., putting files into the specified directory.

Comment: @Dave Newton - I'm still pretty new to Ruby, and I have never done this in particular, so can you be more clear as to what kind of output statements and where I would put them?  thanks :)

Comment: What kind? The same kind that is outputting something now. Where, wherever you want to know something, e.g., to display the expected filename, the full path of the output file so you can look for it in the right place, etc.

Comment: I put a `puts` in front of line 9 `filename = "output/thanks_#{id}.html"` and got a list of 19 files that looked like `output/thanks_19.html  `  and now I see the folder in the directory as well :) thanks!

Comment: In accordance with your actual question why not learn about `TDD` (Test Driven Development) and `BDD` (Behavior Driven Development). There are tons of gems available for testing that will allow you to write tests to ensure that your code does what it is supposed to. `rspec` and `cucumber` are some of the more popular ones but ruby comes built with `Test::Unit` and `MiniTest` as well

Comment: thank you @ engineersmnky I actually just went through a bunch of Test First coding challenges/tests which introduced me to TTD and although at this stage I find it a little frustrating, I **definitely** see the value in it and once I get the hang of it will probably develop within that model. If you know of any particularly wonderful resources for me to learn more I would love to check them out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've (ever so slightly) modified your `save_thank_you_letters` method to spit out some helpful information as it writes files:

```
def save_thank_you_letters(id, form_letter)
  Dir.mkdir("output") unless Dir.exists? ("output")
  filename = "output/thanks_#{id}.html"
  File.open(filename, 'w') do |file|
    file.puts form_letter
    puts "Wrote ID: #{id} to #{filename}"
  end
end
```

The line `puts "Wrote ID: #{id} to #{filename}"` will print the ID and file path of the message it has written. You can place additional `puts "Your text here..."` throughout your Ruby logic to print more information to the console as you see fit.

Side note: in general, **it's a super bad idea to post your personal API keys to any public forums**. If this key is private/unique to you, delete it and request a new one. *Anyone* can now impersonate your account at Sunlight Labs.

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much for that bit of code! It is something I will definitely use when I am writing my own files like this (as it is this is part of an assignment and I think they want it a specific way). But that is super helpful for future reference :)  Also thanks for the tip about the API, because I didn't realize it's so dangerous to post them, but this one is part of a tutorial and public to anyone who uses the tutorial anyways. But now that I know, I will never be posting my own API's !!! lol! Thanks a lot for your response

Comment: I'm glad you found the reply helpful, though it doesn't sound like it solved your problem. Were you able to verify the files were written? You should be able to follow the paths that were printed to your screen when you ran the code. More specifically, you should see a folder named `output` in the same directory as your Ruby file.

Comment: Yes, I actually solved it right before I saw your answer. Another person Kinda started me in the right direction suggesting I use some outputs to find my files, it's in the comments under the question. From there I was able to figure out the rest. But I'm actually going to mark your response as answered, because had I not already solved it, yours would have definitely been the one to get me there ;) Plus you gave some good advice. lol. thanks again!